# In a synchrotron, do electrons make periodic recoils?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons, accelerator-physics

Synchrotron radiation happens because circular motion of electrons produce a tangential acceleration-- or something along those lines.

Point is, photons are produced by these accelerated electrons.

As far as I know, emission of photons act as a brake and slows electrons down.

My question is this.

Given that photons are emitted in a quantized way, I.e. can only take certain energies, I would think that this is not a continuous process. Rather, these emissions would take place at a regular frequency (I assume this frequency is not the one of the emissions).

Is this true? Do electrons emit photons one by one, with a distinct recoil each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more complicated question than it appears on its face.

A free electron has a *continuous* energy spectrum. This means that the photons it emits are not constrained to quantized values like they would be for a bound system.

Photons are unusual in that they don't have any mass. Formally the *number* of photons emitted in bremsstrahlung radiation is *infinite*- an infinite number of very low energy photons that sum up to a finite energy. Since any method of detecting photons necessarily has an energy threshold, you can only ever detect a finite number of photons, but that exact number depends on how sensitive your detector is.

That said, for a given threshold, yes, the electron appears to emit the photons one at a time, with a distinct recoil for each one. It's just that you can never be sure how many photons below your detection threshold that you may have missed.

And as a practical matter in a real synchrotron, you have so many electrons that you can ignore the recoils and trajectories of individual particles and deal with averages instead.

Comment: Wow. So there are photons that are not multiple of some Planck constant?

Comment: Also thank you for this valuable answer.

Comment: Do you really get recoil if nothing is measuring the individual photons or the electron? I'd imagine that in bremsstrahlung we actually initially get an entangled state of the electron + a state of indefinite photon number (the radiation), and you only get definite recoil events if you either position a photon detector or measure the electron position to high accuracy (but how you'd do that without disturbing its circular motion I'm not sure).

Comment: Actuallly there are so many fascinating things in your answer. Infinite number of photons. How can this integrate to a finite energy?

Comment: @Exocytosis Just as an illustration, imagine there's 1 photon of $1~\rm eV$, 1 of $.5~\rm eV$, 1 of $.25~\rm eV$ and so on. There are an infinite number, but the energy converges to $2~\rm eV$.

Comment: Is this a mere illustration or is this really what happens? Not talking about negative powers of 2, but the sum of these infinite photons being integrable?

Comment: @Winston Yes, the integrals converge.